# Is closure of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ always a countable union of closed intervals?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

The title pretty much is the question (by "closed interval" I mean to include possibly "degenerate" closed intervals consisting of a single point). The plausibility argument (I wouldn't quite call it a "proof") that leads me to think the answer is "yes" goes something like this:

We know the open set $O$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals, call them $o_i$. It seems the closure of $O$ can, in general, introduce two kinds of limit points not already members of $O$:

- Any endpoint of an $o_i$ (thus each $o_i$ "becomes" a closed interval in $\overline{O}$)
- A point which is some finite distance from every $o_i$, but is the limit to which some (infinite) subset of the $o_i$ converges. It seems plausible (though I don't have a *proof*) that there would be at most countably many such limit points.

By this reasoning, the closure of any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be equal to some countable union of closed (possibly "degenerate") intervals.

Is this right? Or am I missing some case where it fails to hold?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question! Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is **negative**: let $U$ be the open set consisting of an open interval of length $d\over 3$ placed in the center of each "deleted interval" in the construction of the Cantor set of length $d$. The closure of $U$ contains, in addition to the obvious countable collection of closed intervals, every point in the Cantor set itself.

(This construction is closely related to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920965/28111) to an old question of mine, incidentally.)

Comment: Ah, yes. The Cantor set is starting to seem like the universal counter-example to every seemingly plausible but wrong intuition about the topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks.